# The last line within the while loop prints after each iteration of the second loop.How to print it once after receiving the given command?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested

```
package toto.com;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class redactor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);


        String tournament = scanner.nextLine();

        double won = 0;
        double lost = 0;
        double receptacle = 0;

        //Input
          //Ballers
          //3
          //87
          //63
          //56
          //65
          //75
          //64
          //Sharks
          //4
          //64
          //76
          //65
          //86
          //68
          //99
          //45
          //78
          //End of tournaments
          // the output is at the bottom
  


        while (!tournament.equals("End of tournaments")) {
            int matches = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
            receptacle += matches;

            for (int i = 0; i < matches; i++) {//TODO redact of needed to 0 and <
                int points1 = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
                int points2 = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

                if (points1 > points2) {
                    won++;
                    System.out.printf("%nGame %d of tournament %s: win with %d points.", i, tournament, points1 - points2);
                } else {
                    lost++;
                    System.out.printf("%nGame %d of tournament %s: lost with %d points.", i, tournament, points2 - points1);
                }

            }


            System.out.printf("%n%.2f%% matches win%n" +
                    "%.2f%% matches lost", (won / receptacle) * 100, (lost / receptacle) * 100); // As far as I'm concerned printing it outside of the loop using if statement doesnt't seem to work because the condition within is always true. 
            tournament = scanner.nextLine();

        }
    }


}
   
   

   //Desired Output
    //Game 1 of tournament Ballers: win with 24 points.
    //Game 2 of tournament Ballers: lost with 9 points.
    //Game 3 of tournament Ballers: win with 11 points.
    //Game 1 of tournament Sharks: lost with 12 points.
    //Game 2 of tournament Sharks: lost with 21 points.
    //Game 3 of tournament Sharks: lost with 31 points.
    //Game 4 of tournament Sharks: lost with 33 points.
    //28.57% matches win
    //71.43% matches lost
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading your question as asking how to get the win/loss numbers to print only after the tournament is ended. To accomplish this move your final printf statement after your while loop. Then it will only run once after your tournament is over.

```
while (!tournament.equals("End of tournaments")) {
    int matches = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    receptacle += matches;

    for (int i = 0; i < matches; i++) {//TODO redact of needed to 0 and <
        int points1 = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        int points2 = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());

        if (points1 > points2) {
            won++;
            System.out.printf("%nGame %d of tournament %s: win with %d points.", i, tournament, points1 - points2);
        } else {
            lost++;
            System.out.printf("%nGame %d of tournament %s: lost with %d points.", i, tournament, points2 - points1);
        }

    }

    // Location of line to move from
    tournament = scanner.nextLine();

}
// Location of print statment to move to
System.out.printf("%n%.2f%% matches win%n" +
        "%.2f%% matches lost", (won / receptacle) * 100, (lost / receptacle) * 100); // As far as I'm concerned printing it outside of the loop using if statement doesnt't seem to work because the condition within is always true.
```

output

```
Game 0 of tournament Ballers: win with 24 points.
Game 1 of tournament Ballers: lost with 9 points.
Game 2 of tournament Ballers: win with 11 points.
Game 0 of tournament Sharks: lost with 12 points.
Game 1 of tournament Sharks: lost with 21 points.
Game 2 of tournament Sharks: lost with 41 points.
Game 3 of tournament Sharks: lost with 33 points.
28.57% matches win
71.43% matches lost
```

Comment: It prints the statistics within the for-loop and afterwards the program proceeds to end.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make the distinction between the game stats and the tournament win/loss stats more explicit. Can you confirm that the output in my answer matches your expectations.

Comment: It's ineffective. It doesn't print the final statistics(tournament win/loss) as I've mentioned above. Any other suggestions?

Comment: That is odd as it prints the win/loss stats on my end. Could you provide your updated version of the code with the above suggestion included?